# What is "workon" when using the Django framework?

Tags: django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

What is `workon` when using the Django framework?

Is it true that when using `virtualenv`, then you need to activate or deactivate, and so forth, but if you install and use `virtualenvwrapper`, then you don't have to do all that and can just create environments and use `workon` to switch?   Can someone give an introduction as to how `virtualenv`, `virtualenvwrapper`, and `workon` relate to each other?

Answer (score 5):

`workon project_a` means that you switch the the virtual environment `project_a`. In other words, when you type `python` or `python manage.py` you have access to the `project_a` libraries.

> Is it true that when using virtualenv, then you need to activate or deactivate, and so forth, but if you install and use virtualenvwrapper, then you don't have to do all that and can just create environments and use workon to switch?

Yes. Roughly, `workon project_b` is the same than:

```
deactivate
source project_b/venv/path/bin/activate
```

Comment: I think it is cool to abstract a series of commands to just "workon"

Answer (score 3):

`virtualenvwrapper` is a package providing shortcuts for working with `virtualenv`, such as `workon`, `mkvirtualenv`, and others. This has nothing to do with django, but is commonly used alongside it. The docs are here:

https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/